# How to add horizontal scroll bar in Orbeon Form Builder

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

We have created a table with 14 columns in Repeat Section using Form Builder. Now we can't see cells. Because of narrowing of cell width. How to add a scroll bar to Form Builder to see cells normally?
**UPDATED!**
Now it looks like: [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejiuwagngjhv2bd/FB.jpg)

Comment: I imagine you should be able to do this with CSS. Could you update your question to include a screenshot showing how it looks like right now?

Comment: @avernet, the question still actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to do the trick for a simple example I put together here:

```
.xbl-fr-grid { overflow: scroll }
.xbl-fr-grid .fr-grid { width: 1500px; max-width: none }
```

But you might want to adapt this to your own situation, for which using the Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug, as well CSS knowledge will come in handy.

Comment: Hi, Alessandro! Thank you for your help. If a scroll bar will automatically appear when a many horizontal cells will be created in FB, then it will be usefull. How do you think?

Comment: Yes, this is what the CSS above will do, at least in the case where I tested it.

Comment: does Orbeon Forms 4.0 Beta 2 supports automatic scroll bar?

Comment: No, it doesn't, and this isn't planned for 4.0. Sorry, but for now this is something you'll need to do by adding your own CSS.